# Embed iframe into a php file

Tags: php, html, iframe

I recently started a new position as a graphic designer for a local nonprofit. I have a little background in HMTL and CSS, but their website runs on PHP and I'm already struggling to work with the code.

I need to add an inline frame to embed a webpage within a specific page on our website. The programmers who built our site didn’t build a user friendly interface where we can embed HTML, so I'm told that I need to add the iframe snippet into the PHP for that page. However, the page I want to edit does not have it's own PHP file. It is a subpage under one of the site's main nav categories. I was able to find a PHP file which corresponds to that main nav category that this subpage falls under. I believe that this is where I would need to add the code. It appears to be a template which structures all of the pages inside of this broader nav category.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm not sure if you can just add HTML to a PHP file as is, or if it needs to be altered a bit. Also I need to know how I could have the PHP template selectively load the desired iframe only on the page that actually needs it - I don't want that iframe to appear in all the other pages that fall within the broader nav category.

The code I need to embed looks like this:

```
    <iframe width="100%" height="800px" src="https://google.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

Comment: so what did you try?

Comment: To be honest .. You're going to have to get into the directory structure --  Learn where everything is -- There's probably `includes` and `requires` that pull in "partial" `php` files to make a whole page.  And .. The `HTML` itself  *MAY* even be in a `MySQL` database ..  That said -- It's really impossible for anyone to answer this question .. and if they do -- They are "guessing"

Comment: @AlexThrift you cant do that cause you try to do "Cross-Sitescripting" this is not allowed. try to find a work-a-round with js/jquery, is my advice.

Answer (score -1):

you can use html as it is on php page.

point 2: you want to show iframe on specific page only...

e.g. on page xyz.php

```
  <?php
   $basename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); /* Returns The Current PHP File Name */

   if ($basename == 'xyz.php'){ ?>

      <iframe width="100%" height="800px" src="https://google.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>

   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the page I want to edit does not have it's own PHP file. Is there any way I could use a URL to target the specific page?

Comment: can you provide code example where you are going to add iframe and more details.. ??